# Changing color of individual characters in text

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

Is it possible to change specific characters of text to a different color than the rest? I would like the first 2 characters "12" to be a different.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("12Text")
                             .foregroundColor(Color("Orange"))
                             .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 17.5))
                                .padding(.top)
                             Spacer()
```

UPDATE:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Text("12")
                             .foregroundColor(Color("Orange"))
                             .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 17.5))
                                .padding(.top)
                            
                            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Text("Text")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("White"))
                                .padding(.top)
                                Spacer()
                            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`+`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/+(_:_:)) operator on `Text` to concatenate them together. I applied a different color to each `Text`, joined them, and then applied the other modifiers.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    HStack {
        (
            Text("12")
                .foregroundColor(.orange) +
            
            Text("Text")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        )
        .bold()
        .font(.system(size: 17.5))
        .padding(.top)
        
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this could work but it gives me an error.. please see my updated post above

Comment: @SummerMacon The problem is using `.padding(.top)` on the 2nd Text. This modifier does not have the return type of `Text`, and the operator doesn't exist for any `View`. Instead, here you may just want `HStack(padding: 0) { /* views */ }` if you need to keep the padding.

Comment: Thanks, still getting a lot of stranger errors (update above)

Comment: @SummerMacon Okay so the two options are to either use `+` where both are of type `Text`, or remove the `+` and use an `HStack` with no spacing. If you are trying to use the padding modifier for _just_ the second Text, you will need to use the HStack. If you meant to apply the padding to _both_ Texts, then wrap the Text in brackets `( )` like I did and do the `+` solution.

Comment: Thanks again! Does the HStack go within the other HStack? And for the other method what do you mean by brackets wrapping Text? Sorry, I am new!

Comment: @SummerMacon Yes, it would be a separate HStack. With the other method, I say 'brackets' (you may know them as 'braces'). See the code in my answer - the two Texts are inside those `(` and `)`. This means that the type of this will be `Text`, and then we apply the modifiers. Without this, the modifiers would _only_ be applied to the second Text - and also the `+` operator will not work since the types are no longer both Text.